# Safari Web Extension icon does not open popup from the overflow (>>) menu

Tags: safari, safari-extension, safari-web-extension

Video showing the bug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQoOYWe0jfE

1. Install any Safari Web Extension from the Mac App Store (e.g. DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials, Bitwarden Password Manager).
2. Resize the Safari window until the extension browser_action icon is forced into the overflow menu (>> at the far right of the toolbar).
3. Open the overflow menu and click the menu item for the extension. Nothing happens.

This even occurs when using the sample extension "Sea Creator" developed by Apple. You can build it and try it out by following the instructions on this page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/developing_a_safari_web_extension

I have filed a Feedback Assitant report for this issue: FB9495287 / http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5035732439662592

Anyone know what's going on here? Or does anyone have a workaround to get the extension popup to appear when invoked from this menu?